# Having trouble with binary quadratic forms.

Tags: number-theory

A quadratic form represents an integer $n$ if there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x,y)=n$.  It is proper if $\gcd{(x,y)}=1$.  It is said that if $f(x,y)=n$ and $\gcd{(x,y)}=g$, then $g^2|n$.  My question in regards to the material is this; why is it necessary that $g^2|n$?

Knowing $\gcd{(x,y)}=g$, I know that there must exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=g$  Also $$a^2x^2+2abxy+b^2y^2=n=g^2  $$
This is clearly a quadratic form and it is such that $g^2=n$.  Is this the reason?

EDIT:  I made a mistake originally that stated $\gcd{(x,y)}=1$ when it was my intention to write $\gcd{(x,y)}=g$  This I hope clarifies what I was asking, but I believe that I understand why it is such that $g^2|n$.  (Since $\gcd{(x,y)}=g, x=gk_1, y=gk_2$.  If $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=n$, substituting for $x,y$ gives the desired result I believe..)

Comment: No. Why should this be? When decisions can be see there. The formula to find the blog. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=206450

Comment: @individ, I am looking through all the stuff and I'm still unsure why my example doesn't show $g^2|n$?

Comment: Actually, I think I see why...$(x,y)=g \Rightarrow x=gk_1, y=gk_2$.  Then $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=n \Rightarrow a(gk_1)^2+b(gk_1)(gk_2)+c(gk_2)^2=n=g^2(ak_1^2+bk_1k_2+ck_2^2)$

Comment: And what next? The equations are solved by the given $a,b,c,n$. Decisions of this kind have not always.

Comment: What do you mean "what next"?

Comment: Try this example: $3x^2-xy-2y^2=-8$

Comment: I do not see a sensible question here. In your first paragraph, what is $g?$ Meanwhile, I cannot make any sense of this regardless of what $g$ means. Please read your post carefully and re-write things, which are currently just contradictory.

Comment: I fixed what I was asking.  I had a typo.  $\gcd{(x,y)}=g$, not $1$.

Comment: Yes, the edit answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so we have an answer: if $\gcd(x,y)=g$, then $g^2$ divides $x^2$ and $xy$ and $y^2$, so it divides $f(x,y)$, which is $n$.